# JSON encode_decode weird behave PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have array input in HTML Form as below

```
<select name="age[]" id="ageFrom">..Age Options..</select>
<select name="age[]" id="ageTo">..Age Options..</select>
```

Upon submission, I am saving data in mysql database as **json_encoded** value like `["20","25"]`

```
foreach($request->request as $key => $value) {
  ProfileSettings::create([
    'uid' => $curMID,
    'code' => 'preference',
    'key' => $key,
    'value' => json_encode($value),
    'serialized' => 1
  ]);
});
```

Now, when it get this value from DB and try to decode it as

```
$val = json_decode(["20", "25"]) OR json_decode(["20", "25"], true)
```

My DB returns value like

[image]

Then i get an error like

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Kindly help me to get 20 and 25 as `$val[0]` and `$val[1]`

Comment: json_decode is expecting a string and you are giving an array, try `json_decode("[20,21]")`

Comment: that array value is directly from database...

Comment: You can provide the php code that insert data ?

Comment: I have updated the PHP code

Comment: It may be getting the string from the database, but your code is showing an array structure, not a string. Show the actual code you're using, and not the value you think is going in. Also, `htmlspecialchars` != `json_decode`, so that may not be where your error is coming from.

Comment: try to use json_encode outside  `ProfileSettings`

Comment: I have updated an image of value that i m getting from DB

Comment: If `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` is the exact error given, then this error is **not** coming from json_decode. Find out where in you're code you're using `htmlspecialchars()` or you're using `$val`

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, you're calling `json_decode` on a php array `[ ]`.

It expects a string, which it'll convert to an array.

Perhaps you wanted to use `json_encode` instead? If so, change your code to:

```
$val = json_encode(["20", "25"]) OR json_encode(["20", "25"], true)
```

Comment: encoded data is already saved in database while saving,, please have a look into my question

Comment: What is the exact value you're passing to json_decode?

Comment: direct value that i get from DB as `json_decode($dbquery->value)`

Comment: Try running a `var_dump($dbquery->value)`. Maybe the function you're using is already decoding it.

Comment: I have updated an image of value that i m getting from DB

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling htmlspecialchars somewhere else?

Comment: Nopp.. not at all,,

Comment: Then something else is. json_decode doesn't call htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value coming from the data base is `["20", "25"]` and when is inserted in the `json_decode()` function is interpreted as an array.

To solve the problem insert the value in between double quotes.

```
$val = json_decode("$result") or $val = json_decode('["20", "25"]')
```